# How to use subdirectories in a dart .polymer 1 project?

Tags: dart

I generate a new Dart.Polymer1.0 in Webstorm. It has a default element `<main-app>` in directory `\web`.

I create a new element `<t-file>`, also in \web, which is used/called by `<main-app>`. All works fine.

I then move `<t-file>` into a subdirectory of web - `\web\view\t_file.html`.

WebStorm is happy - I can CTRL-B to `t_file.html` etc. There are no warnings or complaints.  But the app shows a blank page when it runs (= not running!)

I move `<t-file>` back up to be a sibling of `<main-app>`, and it works again.

I must be missing something, but what is it?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I have "found the answer".
1) Close the project in Webstorm, and reopen it - it then works.
2) Do not remove imports that webstorm says are unused - because they are!  In 'main-app.dart' I had

```
  import 'package:rm5/view/t_file.dart';
```

which was greyed-out. But it must be there for it to work.
S

Comment: Yup, because you don't use anything directly,  they are shown as unused, but mirrors (development time) and transformers (build time) creat html import tags from annotations in imported files. Without the import the html tags are not generated. If the imported file contains a class (for example a Polymer element) you can make the import used by adding a codedoc comment like `/// [MyImportedElement]` somewhere in the importing file (where codedoc comments are valid)